# more different items in one list

Tags: c#, list, items

I want to make a list with different items or what I should call it. I mean for example.

```
public class form1
{
    public List<string> information = new List<string>();
}
```

And I want It to contain information from textboxes with Id, name and phonenumber like this:

```
private void btnForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 Form1= new Form2(); 

    Form1.Show();

    class Form2a = new Form2();
    a.information.Add(txtId.Text);
    a.information.Add(txtName.Text);
    a.information.Add(txtPhonenumber.Text);
}
```

Then it will be filled with what we can call different customers who have different Id, names and phonenumbers.

Then I want to get the information to another form.

Can someone please help me or give me tips on how?

Comment: Instead of a `List<string>` use a `List<Customer>` where `Customer` is a custom class with these properties.

Comment: So, what problem are you currently having?

Comment: You're calling an instance of `Form2`, `Form1`.  That's really, *really* mean.

Comment: Okay so I use list<customer> instead but will that solve my problem?

Answer (score 5):

You should make a custom class named `Customer` or similar, and create a `List<Customer>`.  This will allow you to convert your UI elements (the text boxes) into properly typed `Customer` instances and store them.

Answer (score 3):

You should group that information using a `class` then create and add instances of that class to your list. Below is an example class and some other code you may find helpful. Feel free to ask if you have questions.

```
public class PersonInfo
{
     public string Name;
     public string Id;
     public string phoneNumber;
}


List<PersonInfo> persons = new List<PersonInfo>();
// after reading values
persons.Add(new PersonInfo(txtName.Text, txtId.Text, txtPhoneNumber.Text));

// if you don't have a constructor like that defined;

personse.Add(new PersonsInfo {
                    Name = txtName.Text;
                    Id = txtId.Text;
                    PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text;
             });

// get a user by Id

PersonInfo p = persons.Where(x => x.Id == "that other Id").FirstOrDefault();

if (p != null)
   // we found our person
```

Comment: I think it looks great but I have some problems.
I created a new class for the personinfo and in that class I have putted the list also. But I cant get it to work

Comment: @user3076791 your class definitions is quite a bit different than mine. Follow my code more closely. You dont' want the `persons` list to be a property of the class. You should remove that prop from `Class1` then declare a `List<Class1>` in the same place you had `List<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

What am I doing wrong here?
This is in form1

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        Class1 a = new Class1();
        a.persons.Add(new persons (txtName.Text, txtId.Text, txtPhonenumber.Text));

    }
```

this is class1 a new class i have created

{
    class Class1
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Id;
        public string phoneNumber;
        public List persons = new List();
    }

}

Comment: I don't get it where it goes wrong. i have copy and pasted the code you just posted and still gets errors. Does it work for you?